# NodeMailer send HTML email with template from database

Tags: javascript, nodemailer

In my app I have set nodemailer to send out emails. The app is built with Vue and Firebase.
I need to modify email templates from UI, so they are saved in HTML format in database.
Inside these templates I need to be able to use dynamic values.

This is the method to create the email:

```
 const mailOptions = {
     from: "Test",
     to: req.body.email,
     subject: "New email from" + " " + req.body.email,
     html: req.body.arenile.email_template
  };
```

The content of `req.body.arenile.email_template` in FireStore is:

```
<p>Date: ${req.body.reservation_date} </p><p>Email: ${req.body.email}</p>
```

The problem is that variables are not evaluated and printed out on email as they are.

I tried:

```
html: ` ${req.body.arenile.email_template}`
```

but it doesn't solve it.

If I use:

```
html: `<p>Date: ${req.body.reservation_date} </p><p>Email: ${req.body.email}</p>`
```

it works fine. `${req.body.email}` is printed as `email@example.com`

But:

```
html: ` ${req.body.arenile.email_template}`
```

doesn't. `${req.body.email}` is printed as `${req.body.email}`

I am not sure if I need to escape HTML differently or if request data are being evaluated in the wrong place..

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried `html: req.body.arenile.email_template` instead of `html: \` ${req.body.arenile.email_template}\``?

Comment: yes, same result

Comment: Any outputs from the console? (or try to `console.dir(req.body.arenile.email_template)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this way:

```
var html = req.body.arenile.email_template;
html = html.replace('{{email}}', req.body.email);
html: html
```

Then using `{{email}}` will print the corrent value.